# Как прочитать текстовый документ построчно так, чтобы возможно было работать с каждой строкой отдельно?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

**Есть текстовый документ, в котором такие записи:**

```
text;31
text;0
text;12
text;5
text;0
```

Моя задача сделать скрипт, который будет проверять изменение последних цифр после разделителя (`,`).
При чтении файла нужно его построчно записать в список с помощью readlines? Тогда как потом его изменить для дальнейшей роботы?

Comment: Считывайте файл через readlines, изменять можно через writelines, вот только зачем его переписывать в том же скрипте, что проверяет?

Comment: Опишите что именно происходит с файлом в процессе работе скрипта? Так то действие достаточно тривиальное: `lines_list = file.readlines()` и все. Поэтому суть вопроса непонятна

Comment: А что хотим получить в результате? В чем суть "дальнейшей работы"?. Нужно ли производить какие-то действия в случае если данные изменились?

Comment: кого его? файл или список?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin файл

Comment: @Namerek в результате при изменении уведомить в телеграмме через бота

Comment: @cauf Нужно из файла достать данные, проверить не изменились ли цифры в конце каждой строки (нужно знать в какой именно строке). Если изменились, уведомить через телеграмм бота. Я не особо понимаю как это сделать из за того что через readlines получается список и его не получится разделить сплитом (line.split(;))

Comment: @gil9red Мне не нужно изменять текстовый файл в котором хранятся данные. Мне нужно только проверить не изменились ли цифры в конце каждой строки (нужно знать в какой именно строке). Если изменились, уведомить через телеграмм бота.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для поставленной задачи вам нужно иметь два файла: с текущим и предыдущим состоянием для сверки значений. Вообще, предыдущие значения можно хранить и в памяти в виде какой-либо структуры (например словаря) или в бд (sqlite).

Отмечу сразу, что это не самый оптимальный способ решения поставленной задачи, но он самый простой в понимании, что именно происходит в данными

```py
# считываем данные из файла с текущими данными
with open(r'path\to\current_file.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as cur_fl:
    # получим список всех строк
    cur_data_lines = cur_fl.readlines()
    # на основе списка создадим словарь ключ:значение
    cur_data_dict = {
        ln.split(';')[0]:ln.split(';')[1]  # разделение строки по ';' - левая часть в ключ, правая в значение
        for ln in cur_data_lines
    }

# то же самое, но для файла с предыдущими значениями
with open(r'path\to\prev_file.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as prev_fl:
    prev_data_lines = prev_fl.readlines()
    prev_data_dict = {ln.split(';')[0]:ln.split(';')[1] for ln in prev_data_lines}

# обход по циклу всех пар ключ:значение из файла с текущими данными
for k, v in cur_data_dict.items():
    # если ключ есть в предыдущем файле и значение не равно предыдущему
    if (k in prev_data_dict.keys()) and (v != prev_data_dict[k]):
        # отправить сообщение в телеграм (здесь вызов бота написан в качестве placeholder - надо подставить свой код)
        telegram_bot.send_message(f'Для ключа {k} значение изменилось на {v}')

# переносим значения текущего файла в файл с предыдущими данными
# открывает файл с предыдущими данными на запись
with open(r'path\to\prev_file.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as prev_fl:
    # открываем файл с текущими данными на чтение
    with open(r'path\to\current_file.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as cur_fl:
        # записываем в файл с предыдущими файлами то, что прочли из файла с текущими
        prev_fl.write(cur_fl.read())
```

Comment: `cur_data_dict = dict(ln.split(';') for ln in cur_data_lines)` — и проще и нагляднее

Comment: Не сильно нагляднее - не совсем понятно, как именно будет образована пара ключ:значение. Опять же, я исходил из задачи сделать код простым к чтению и понятным для новичка.